# How can I exclude my enemies from spawning in certain zones generated at random?

Tags: java, android, game-mechanics, andengine, android-studio

I have a code where I randomly generate enemy spawn position, but I want to exclude some areas since it's colliding with some sprites it shouldn't collide with.

This is the code where I generate the random points from where the enemy is coming from (from top,down, left and right):

```
int z = ran.nextInt(4);
int r1 = ran.nextInt(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH+1);
int r2 = ran.nextInt(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH+ 1);
int r3 = ran.nextInt(GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT+ 1);
int r4 = ran.nextInt(ControlJuego.CAMARA_HEIGHT+ 1);
```

I set the position of the enemy with the random variable:

```
if (var == 1) {
   newEnemy.getSpriteEnemy().setPosition(0, r1);
} else if (var == 2) {
   newEnemy.getSpriteEnemy().setPosition(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH, r2);
} else if (var == 3) {
   newEnemy.getSpriteEnemy().setPosition(r3, 0);
} else if (var == 4) {
   newEnemy.getSpriteEnemy().setPosition(r4, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT);
 }
```

Later I move the enemies to the center of the screen.

An image for better vistualizatio of the problem:

[image: Game]

I don't want my enemies to ever spawn behind any of the corner sprites or to collide with any of the corner sprites before entering the screen. How can I solve this problem? How can I exclude this areas?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: either you know how to create a function that you can use to shape the distribution. or you test for collision and discard + retry. (russian roulette)

Comment: Principe: while(pos1.Intersects(pos2)) generateRandomPos(pos1);

Comment: @v.oddou I was thinking of discarding enemies that collisioned outside the screen, but I would be loosing some enemies so i would have a lower frequency of enemies on screen than I would want. But I think I could still implement the method for extra safety.

Comment: you don't have a lower frequency if you loop "while not success" for each spawn. the frequency control should be at a higher level. (in the function calling "rand enemy spawn")

Comment: @v.oddou How can I detect collisions out of the screen/before entering the screen though?

Comment: You actually do it, as a dry run, and if the test fails, you need to restart. so in the place where you just have a random spawn today, you need to surround it with a loop (while not success).

Answer (score 3):

If your corner sprites are as simple as you show here, you can avoid collisions by changing how you generate the random positions.

E.g. for the top, you currently generate a random int between 0 and `width` (well, ignoring that you seem to have transposed width and height in some spots).
So suppose you have `yellowWidth`, the width of the yellow object at the top border, and `greenWidth`, the width of the green object similarly.

So the space between yellow and green is `width - (yellowWidth + greenWidth)`.
If you generate your top value with `ran.nextInt((GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH + 1) - (yellowWidth + greenWidth));` and add `yellowWidth`, it should fall between the two.

Given that your enemies aren't points but areas, you'll need to add a buffer to the sizes of yellowWidth and greenWidth. E.g. if you have `enemyWidth`, the final calculation would be something like:

`int r1 = yellowWidth + enemyWidth/2 + ran.nextInt((GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH + 1) - (yellowWidth + greenWidth + enemyWidth));`

Just do the same with the other sides, switching to height and other-colored sprites as needed.

Comment: I tried your method (only changing the value of random values) and it didn't work. I still have enemies coming from the corners.

Comment: Might be because you've got height and width flipped for some spawn positions. r1 and r2 should use CAMERA_HEIGHT, r3 and r4 should use _WIDTH, assuming setPosition is (x, y).

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Sorry it's not working, but comments aren't the right place to try and remote debug something. If you want more help you can create a chat room and invite me, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Chris is right about the first method (distribution shaping).

Now the second (roulette): that's the method I implemented in my game.
full source here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/extremecarnage

```
bool HostilesManager::SpawnHostile(SPAWN_POSITION_en spawnPos, int isprite)
{
    // create a new car
    CarsManager::CarAcsor newcar = ChiefManager::GetCarsManager()->Push(spriteFiles[isprite]);
    hostiles.push_front(newcar);
    // *hostiles.front().pcar and *newcar are aliases
    const int bordw = ChiefManager::GetTerrainManager()->GetBorderWidth();
    const Vector2i terrSize = ChiefManager::GetTerrainManager()->GetSize();

    // spawn ennemys on the far right position only
    if (spawnPos == SP_LEVEL_RIGHT)
    {
        // random vertically, but 500 pixel from the left-end
        newcar->SetPosition(terrSize.x + 500,
                            bordw +
                            rnd.Get(terrSize.y - bordw * 2));
    }
    else // MIDDLE
    {
        Rect rc(newcar->rect);

        // same tech than the terrain generator
        int security = 0;
        bool intersect = true;
        const int max_repeats = terrSize.x / rc.w + terrSize.y / rc.h;   // fast heuristic
        while (intersect && security < max_repeats) // util it fits
        {
            // random generation here
            rc.pos.x = bordw + 50 + rnd.Get(terrSize.x - rc.w - (bordw << 1));
            rc.pos.y = bordw + rnd.Get(terrSize.y - rc.h - (bordw << 1));
            // verify intersection with decors objects:
            intersect = ChiefManager::GetCollisionsAndProbing()->IntersectRect(rc);
            ++security;
        }
        if (security == max_repeats)    // that didnt work
        {
            hostiles.pop_front();
            return false;
        }
        newcar->SetPosition(rc.pos.x,
                            rc.pos.y);
    }
    // set the target
    hostiles.front().target.x = 0;
    hostiles.front().target.y = 64 + rnd.Get(terrSize.y - 128);
    // random start direction :
    newcar->angle = rnd.Get(359);

    newcar->GiveWeapon(game_vars::g_minigun_id);
    newcar->SetIAClass(iaClassID_simple, ChiefManager::GetIAManager());
    BOOST_ASSERT(newcar->GetIAClassID() == iaClassID_simple);

    if (isprite > 0)    // that's for stronger ennemies
    {
        newcar->health = 200;
        newcar->SetIAClass(iaClassID_strong, ChiefManager::GetIAManager());
        BOOST_ASSERT(newcar->GetIAClassID() == iaClassID_strong);

        newcar->GiveWeapon(game_vars::g_heavymg_id);   // and more dangerous
    }

    return true;
}
```

ok so you get more than you need but the crucial part is the russian roulette loop that retries when a collision happens. as you can see, it ensures termination by using an arbitrary maximum limit on iterations.